# How to get and set Luminous intensity of the screen of iPhone or iPad?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I see that you can set the relative brightness through what documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617830-brightness with a number between 0.0 and 1.0. However, I would like to get and set the absolute luminous intensity in cd/m2 or lx or lm.

So far I could not find the APIs, while it seems the max absolute luminous intensity is known as mentioned at https://www.gsmarena.com/apple_iphone_8-review-1664p3.php.

Do you happen to know how?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an API to set the brightness of the screen in something other than an abstract value between `0.0 - 1.0`.

Perhaps you can map the known max brightness to the `0.0 - 1.0` range yourself, but I'm not sure that would be accurate.

Comment: And even if I know the absolute value of max brightness, I am not sure if 0-1 is linear, so some other formulas of progressing.